# How to validate and correct data in excel in realtime?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I know excel has the data validation feature but is there a way to automatically apply the changes for the user instead of prompting them that there is an issue?

For example, we have a general spreadsheet template for our internal system to add items. In the first column, for Item No, there can't be any illegal characters. So if the user enters AN-XR10LP/1 in A1 and then clicks on the next cell, I would want the validation to correct the A1 value to be ANXR10LP1 without the user doing anything.

Any ideas on how I can start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only accomplish this with VBA. Try the code below. It may need to be tweaked if you have Data Validation on the cells.

Place this module in the Worksheet Object where you want your data validated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then '-> make sure row count is 1 and target is in column A, can further refine if needed

    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = CleanString(Target.Value)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = strValue
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub

Function CleanString(str As String) As String

CleanString = Replace(str, "-", "")
CleanString = Replace(CleanString, "/", "")
'...
'keep adding replacements as needed


End Function
```

Comment: You'll end up in a loop here if you don't either turn off events or have some other way to not process your own updated value...

Comment: @TimWilliams. I totally see what you mean, but when I tested this on a (small) sample set, it seemed to work without hitch. I did edit my code for best practice though.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how to put it inside the worksheet object? I tried to create a new macro but it wasn't working that way!

Comment: @user7954 -> this http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html does a nice job for you.

Comment: Hey Scott, on the first If statement line I'm trying to do:
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Row >= 2 Then

To make it skip the headers but it keeps making Excel crash!

Comment: Try this ... `If Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then ... If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then ...` . So break it up, so it only passes the `rows.Count` first. It might be breaking if you have a multi-cell range selected.

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler for Worksheet_Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

In the handler, see where `Target` points to, and apply validation logic basing on that.

Make sure you ignore the `Change` event raised when you write back corrected values:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    static self_protect as boolean

    if self_protect then exit sub


    ...
    self_protect = true
    Target.Value = "corrected value"
    self_protect = false
    ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of self_protect, why not just turn `Application.EnableEvents` off and then back on?

Comment: @Doug - If you're ever running your code in an environment where there may be other code which expects to handle events then turning them off may cause problems.  Sometimes better to be more selective.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that's true, but I wouldn't assume that to be the case. I find code like the above harder to maintain than using the built-in `Application.EnableEvents`, so I'd say it's best to go with it unless a custom approach like GSerg's is needed.  I guess your point is you can't know which is the case.