# Value is not updating when trying to increment by 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a `do while` loop and I'm trying to increment the counter value, so that the loop can eventually end, but the value isn't updating to its increment.

I have tried to use other incremental processes from other languages that I know, but I have now found that these don't work in VBA.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dayCount As Integer
    Dim trafficCount As Integer

    dayCount = 0
    i = 1

    Do While i < 25
        Do While Not Range("C9").Offset(0, dayCount).Value = ""
            trafficCount = trafficCount + Range("C9").Offset(i, dayCount).Value
            dayCount = dayCount + 1
        Loop
        Range("C9").Offset(i, dayCount).Value = (trafficCount / (dayCount - 1))
        'This is where the error is
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

The `i` value should be updating in the loop until it reaches 25, but each time it goes through the assignment, but the output is always 1.

Comment: Have you tried using 'Next'? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121476/how-can-i-increment-a-counter-and-store-the-result-in-a-variable-in-vbscript

Comment: How do you know that the output is always 1? What is the output?

Comment: The value of `i` outside the subroutine could be something completely different, and if this is the entire subroutine, then one wonders how you know that `i` is always 1 inside the subroutine, although it could be through the debugger.

Comment: Hey there, I have put in break points to step through the loops and each time it completes the incrementation step, the value is still 1.

Comment: Nevermind, I've just figuerd it out (I think). Because this is contained within a worksheet_change sub, each time the average value is input, the sheet has changed, sending it back to the start of the sub, re assigning i = 1. Sorry about this.

Comment: @KesterJansen Yes, you need to [protect from reentrance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12534066/11683).

Comment: ...or use a `Static` variable.